# DELL PowerEdge 2950 stuck on BIOS

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid5, bios

My DELL PowerEdge 2950 is Stuck on BIOS 2.7 screen and does not advance at all, keyboard is not responding either. How should I troubleshoot this issue?

Here is the screen

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Are you sure they keyboard works?  Is it asking for a key press?  How long are you waiting?  What exactly IS on the screen?  What happened before it stopped working?

Comment: @arcesso No errors on screen. Keyboard was tested with another system just now. It just shows BIOS loading and on the top right corner F2,F11,F12 options from which I can't choos any. On screen is [this](http://imgur.com/lGNcN2O)

Comment: @arcesso it sits like that for 10, 15 and counting minutes.

Comment: Any external/USB drives plugged in?  A lot of times that will cause it to hang.

Comment: @BradBouchard I unplugged keyboard and mouse and it started to go at last. Never have I ever would think of this, thank you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to unplug any USB/external drives.  They can cause the server to hang at boot in many instances.